# How can I import parameters from external file using `include?

Tags: verilog

I want to import a set of **parameter** values from an external file into my Verilog source files (not System Verilog).
I am trying this:

For the main module:

```
        module temp (
        `include "file.vh"
        input [WIDTH:0] data_in,
        output reg [WIDTH:0] data_out,
        input clk
    );
        always @(posedge clk) begin
            data_out <= data_in;
        end
    endmodule
```

and a `file.vh` file:

```
    parameter WIDTH = 12;
```

Please correct me here as this code is not working.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: I think all you need to do is include the code in the parameter declaration section.

module temp #(`include "file.vh") (input ... );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters are either declared in the module body or in a separate part of the header:

```
module temp(...);
`include "parameters.vh"
...
endmodule
```

parameters.vh:

```
parameter WIDTH = 12; // Use semicolons to terminate the lines
parameter ANOTHER = 4;
```

Or:

```
module temp #(`include "parameters.vh") (...);
...
endmodule
```

parameters.vh:

```
parameter WIDTH = 12, // Use commas on each line except the last one
parameter ANOTHER = 4
```

Since including a file is just like a copy paste of the code from the included file, you need to be sure the code at the end is valid Verilog.

Answer (score 0):

With verilog95 port declaration styile you can use the following:

```
module temp (data_in, data_out, clk);
   `include "file.vh"
  input [WIDTH:0] data_in;
  output reg [WIDTH:0] data_out;
  input clk;
  ...
endmodule
```

In this case you can use semi-colon-separated parameter statemens in the include file.

With v2k-style of port declarations, as in your example, you must use the `#(...)` declaration syntax to declare parameters before ports. You can still use the `` `include `` syntax  in parenthesis as int @Unn's example:

```
module temp #(`include "file.vh") (...);
```

The requires your parameters to be comma-separated.